# Best way to convert list of lists to list of tuples?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell, erlang-escript

What's the best way to convert a list such as `[[1,2,3],[a,b,c],[4,5,6]]` to a list of tuples like this:

```
[{1,a,4},{2,b,5},{3,c,6}]
```

where tuple N is composed of the Nth element from each of the three sublists? Should I use a tail recursive function, a list comprehension, or some other approach?

Comment: Please explain with the solution to the above problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One elegant solution can be

```
lol2lot([[]|_]) -> [];
lol2lot(LoL) ->
    [ list_to_tuple([hd(L) || L <- LoL]) | lol2lot([tl(L) || L <- LoL]) ].
```

Answer (score 7):

Just use the standard `lists:zip3/3` function:

```
1> [L1,L2,L3] = [[1,2,3],[a,b,c],[4,5,6]].
[[1,2,3],[a,b,c],[4,5,6]]
2> lists:zip3(L1,L2,L3).
[{1,a,4},{2,b,5},{3,c,6}]
```

Or if you'd prefer to avoid extracting the individual lists:

```
3> apply(lists, zip3, [[1,2,3],[a,b,c],[4,5,6]]).
[{1,a,4},{2,b,5},{3,c,6}]
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer in your case list comprehension because:

- it is a short line of code, easy to read,
- it doesn't need a helper function, so the operation done is clearly visible.

  `L_of_tuple =  [list_to_tuple(X) || X <- L_of_list].`

If this transformation has to be done in many places, it is better to write it in a separate function, and then any solution (even body recursion with caution) is good for me.

Comment: Please give the explanation with the solution of the above problem .

Answer (score 0):

For example so:

```
L =  [[1,2,3],[a,b,c],[4,5,6]].
Size = length(L).
T = [fun(I)->list_to_tuple([lists:nth(I,lists:nth(J,L)) ||J<-lists:seq(1,Size)]) end(I) || I<-lists:seq(1,Size)].
```